# Insert text with center align

Tags: vba, ms-word

im using this method to add text but it aligned at left.
how to make it center of document?

```
With ActiveDocument.Content
    .InsertAfter "hello world!"
End With
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/84079/center-text-in-word-document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new para is the last one of the document >> use `.paragraphs.last`

```vb
Sub test()

With ActiveDocument.Content
    .InsertParagraphAfter     'to be safe that new content is on its own para = last para of document
    .InsertAfter "hello world!"
    .Paragraphs.Last.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
End With

End Sub
``
```